# Lambda function to assign status

Tags: python, pandas

I have following DF, pasting only part of it for better visibility.
I need to check df_input on number of occurrences of Name pref.
If satisfy the parameter (In this case for all 4 prefixes ['A0L-0', 'A1L-0', 'Z0L-0', 'Z1L-0'] each one should occur only one time per site) => Site should have status OK,
Else either NOK (if number of occurrences for any name pref per site is more than 1)
Or Not exist (if any name pref/site is missing)

```
data = [
    ['KA7022', 'A0L-0'],
    ['KA7022', 'A1L-0'],
    ['KA7022', 'Z0L-0'],
    ['KA7022', 'Z1L-0'],
    ['TA5251', 'A1L-0'],
    ['TA5251', 'Z0L-0'],
    ['TA5251', 'Z1L-0'],
    ['AL7777', 'A0L-0'],
    ['AL7777', 'A0L-0'],
    ['AL7777', 'A1L-0'],
    ['AL7777', 'Z0L-0'],
    ['AL7777', 'Z1L-0']
]
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Site', 'Name pref'])
```

```
Site    Name pref
0   KA7022  A0L-0
1   KA7022  A1L-0
2   KA7022  Z0L-0
3   KA7022  Z1L-0
4   TA5251  A1L-0
5   TA5251  Z0L-0
6   TA5251  Z1L-0
7   AL7777  A0L-0
8   AL7777  A0L-0
9   AL7777  A1L-0
10  AL7777  Z0L-0
11  AL7777  Z1L-0
```

```
def my_func(x, name_pref_list):
    count = 0
    for name_pref in name_pref_list:
        x = x[x['Name pref'] == name_pref]
        #if 0 occurence then Not exist
        if len(x) == 0:
            return 'Not exist'
        #if > 1 occurence then NOK
        if len(x) > 1:
            return 'NOK'
        count = count + 1
    #if count == len(name_pref_list) then OK
    if len(name_pref_list) == count:
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'NOK'

df_result = df_input.groupby('Site').\
                     apply(lambda x: my_func(x, ['A0L-0', 'A1L-0', 'Z0L-0', 'Z1L-0'])).\
                     reset_index(name='Status')
```

As a result i have following

```
    Site    Status
0   AL7777  NOK
1   KA7022  Not exist
2   TA5251  Not exist
```

While I am expecting to have something like this

```
    Site    Status
0   AL7777  NOK
1   KA7022  OK
2   TA5251  Not exist
```

Seems like code does not like accepting function variable as a list.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does *If satisfy the parameter Site* mean?

Comment: In this case for all 4 prefixes ['A0L-0', 'A1L-0', 'Z0L-0', 'Z1L-0'] each one should occur only one time per site

Comment: For `TA5251` each one occurred one time, ['A1L-0', 'Z0L-0', 'Z1L-0']?

Comment: Yes, but A0L-0 is missing. That's why it is Not exist.

Comment: Do you mean to say there will be only 4 unique values in `Name pref` column?

Comment: The problem is with KA7022 it is supposed to be OK, but I am getting Not exist

Comment: It is because you are returning the value even before checking `OK` condition

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
prefixes = ['A0L-0', 'A1L-0', 'Z0L-0', 'Z1L-0']
tmp = (pd.crosstab(df_input['Site'], df_input['Name pref'])
         .reindex(columns=prefixes, fill_value=0)
      )

out = pd.DataFrame({'Site': tmp.index,
                    'Status': np.select([tmp.max(axis=1).gt(1),
                                         tmp.eq(1).all(axis=1)],
                                        ['NOK', 'OK'], 'Not exist')
                    })
```

Output:

```
     Site     Status
0  AL7777        NOK
1  KA7022         OK
2  TA5251  Not exist
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
Name pref  A0L-0  A1L-0  Z0L-0  Z1L-0
Site                                 
AL7777         2      1      1      1 # one value >1 -> NOK
KA7022         1      1      1      1 # all values 1 -> OK
TA5251         0      1      1      1 # else         -> Not exist
```

*Note that the order of the masks in `np.select` defines the priority in case of several matches. With the order which I used, in case of 0/1/2/1 this would assign "NOK", this can of course be changed, for example to give priority to 0.*

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'Site': tmp.index,
                    'Status': np.select([tmp.eq(0).any(axis=1),
                                         tmp.eq(1).all(axis=1)],
                                        ['Not exist', 'OK'], 'NOK')
                    })
```

And to handle mixed 0/1/2 as a separate case:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'Site': tmp.index,
                    'Status': np.select([tmp.eq(0).any(axis=1) & tmp.max(axis=1).le(1), # a value < 0, no value >1
                                         tmp.eq(1).all(axis=1), # all values == 1
                                         tmp.max(axis=1).gt(1) &  tmp.min(axis=1).gt(0) # one value > 1, no 0
                                        ],
                                        ['Not exist', 'OK', 'NOK'],
                                        'other')
                    })
```

Comment: 2-0-1-1 should be classified as `else`, but it is expected to be classified as `one value`.

Comment: @PandaKim I just added a note on that, this can be tweaked very easily.

Comment: Even though it is good for the code to be short, I think it is a safer answer to use a triple conditions or use exact coditions if use np.select.

Comment: @PandaKim it depends what is the ultimate goal, each condition adds an extra cost (even small). As a dummy example if you had 2 conditions (>0 and <=0), it's worthless to test the second. The advantage of select is to be able to use disjoint conditions. Anyway I added another example with 3 conditions to demonstrate a more generic case, that should be plenty to allow OP to design their own.

Comment: The problem is that duplicate values also occur in the example. Of course, it is convenient to have fewer conditions, but the code that assumes that duplicate values do not occur only in the case of "not exist" may be able to solve the example, but i think it is not safe.

Comment: For the original code, the order of the prefixes matters. If A0L-0 is duplicated and A1L-0 absent won't yield the same output as if A1L-0 is duplicated and A0L-0 is absent, I'm not sure this is a critical point and the expected behavior is anyway undefined. If it is important, then OP should make the rules explicit and there will be a way to handle that ;)

Comment: In my opinion, the use of reindex suggests that the code was written with security in mind. However, I believe it would have been safer to prioritize the assignment of "not exist" in the case that 0 exists when using np.select.

Comment: It's more than security, the `reindex` is needed, else if the dataset is missing one of the prefixes in all rows, all rows might be considered valid.

Comment: I agree that reindex is necessary, and that's why I'm saying that your np.select should also prioritize 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Step1**

make conditions

```
chk = {'A0L-0', 'A1L-0', 'Z0L-0', 'Z1L-0'}
cond1 = df_input.groupby('Site')['Name pref'].agg(lambda x: set(x) == chk)
cond2 = df_input.groupby('Site')['Name pref'].agg(lambda x: len(x) == len(chk))
```

cond1 is checking same with unique value of chk

cond2 is checking over 4(length of chk) or not

**Step2**

then perform boolean masking with the given values to satisfy the condition.

```
out = cond1.mask(~cond1, 'Not exist').mask(cond1 & ~cond2, 'NOK').mask(cond1 & cond2, 'OK').reset_index(name='Status')
```

out

```
    Site    Status
0   AL7777  NOK
1   KA7022  OK
2   TA5251  Not exist
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out, have to add some extra conditions, but idea is clear, appreciate your help =)

Comment: A few remarks, you should reuse `df_input.groupby('Site')['Name pref']`, repeated grouping is inefficient. Also `.agg(lambda x: len(x) == len(chk))` could be vectorized using `.size().eq(len(chk))`.

Comment: @Panda Kim quick question, if I have column df_input['Mode'] for example. And I want to check for extra condition, set OK only if it is in ['2T2R', '4T4R', '32T32R'], I need to write 3rd cond:

Comment: cond3 = df_input.groupby('Site')['Mode'].agg(lambda x: x.isin(['2T2R', '4T4R', '32T32R'])

Comment: And then change output as out = cond1.mask(~cond1, 'Not exist').mask(cond1 & ~cond2 | ~cond3, 'NOK').mask(cond1 & cond2 & cond3, 'OK').reset_index(name='Status')